# Kapt task in error when adding jar built with openapi generator

Tags: android, kapt, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I've been using OpenApi Generator (Maven plug in) for Kotlin for many year but this is new, and I don't know how to get any information.

I already have 2 jars, built with OpenApi Generator, imported correctly into android  but when i add a new one, i receive this error from build phase into Android Studio

`> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsMockDebugKotlin e: Could not load module <Error module>`

and scrolling down in build log I see some more generic information, but not an indication where start to look for the issue:

`Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsMockDebugKotlin'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148) at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282) at`

Any hint on where i should start looking?

Thanks

Edit: it seems that with an older AGP version the very same jar file it's ok.